# Why is my panel.controls empty in one function but not the other one?

Tags: vb.net, function, button, panel

I have a problem in a program i'm developing in vb.net.

I have a pnlFoo that contains a pnlBar.  I use pnlBar in 2 of my functions. In the first one, everything go well and pnlBar show all the label and numeric it has in his controls. The problem is in the second function, using the same panel,it always show my pnlBar as empty like there was no label in it.

Here's my code :

First Function :

```
Private Sub txtItem_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtItem.TextChanged 
        If txtItem.Text <> "" Then
            Dim OrderLine As C_OrderLine = New C_OrderLine(C_Item.load(getIdFromString(txtItem.Text)))
            OrderLine.labelName.Location = New Point(50, 0 + (30 * pnlBar.Controls.Count() / 3)) 'This is a label
            OrderLine.quantity.Location = New Point(0, 0 + (30 * pnlBar.Controls.Count() / 3)) 'This is a NumericUpDown
            OrderLine.labelPrice.Location = New Point(475, 0 + (30 * pnlBar.Controls.Count() / 3)) 'This is a label
            pnlBar.Controls.Add(OrderLine.labelName)
            pnlBar.Controls.Add(OrderLine.quantity)
            pnlBar.Controls.Add(OrderLine.labelPrice)
            Order.OrderLines.Add(OrderLine) 'OrderLines is a List of OrderLine
            txtItem.Text = ""
        End If
    End Sub
```

So when im adding stuff in my pnlBar it works and pnlBar is not empty.

My second Function:

```
 Public Sub clickItem(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) ' Happens everytime a click is detected on a labelName
    For Each lbl As Label In pnlBar.Controls ' HERE pnlBar is empty  
        lbl.BackColor = Color.Gray
    Next
    Dim label As Label = DirectCast(sender, Label)
    label.BackColor = Color.Red
    btnDelete.Enabled = True 'HERE my button will stay disabled.
End Sub
```

So in this funtion, pnlBar is empty and doesnt show any of the items in it.

There are the only 2 place I use pnlBar in my code.

So my question is : 
Why is pnlBar empty and my button not turning to enabled ? How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you have an event handler for every time `labelName` is clicked that calls the `clickItem` sub?

Comment: Yeah, I just found the solution like 30 sec ago ahah, the problem was that i was adding the Handler from a Class and, i dont know for which reason,  in this case , all my form elements are empty.

Comment: To clarify for anyone else who stumbles upon this, the solution was to add `Handles labelName.Click` to the end of `clickItem`, correct? So it looks like this: `Public Sub clickItem(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles labelName.Click`

Comment: humm not really because i have a lot of instance of label name. I just move the line `AddHandler OrderLine.labelName.Click, AddressOf PrincipalForm.clickItem` outside of my class file

Comment: You should post your solution in the answers section

Comment: we dont do SOLVED here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved my problem,

my problem was cause by adding an handler from a class file. When I do this, all my form elements are empty and cant be access. To solve it, i juste move

```
AddHandler OrderLine.labelName.Click, AddressOf PrincipalForm.clickItem
```

outside of my class file into my PrincipalForm .